# Enable scl toolset by default

Tags: docker, centos, llvm

I'm trying to create a docker image where the `llvm-toolset-7` is automatically enabled when the image is run.

The context is this image, since it extends from `rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, is to cross-compile to linux. Since for my purposes I need a recent version of llvm, I need the toolset to be enabled by default when I launch the machine because the cross-complilation command is run by the cross cli and not manually by me.

My attempt at the Dockerfile to make this happen is:

```sh
FROM rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install centos-release-scl -y && \
    yum install llvm-toolset-7 -y && \
    yum install scl-utils -y && \
    echo "source scl_source enable llvm-toolset-7" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

However, when I open the interactive shell in docker desktop, it doesn't default to the bash shell with the toolset enabled.

I'm a pretty frequent Ubuntu user but this image is CentOS based and I'm having trouble understanding toolsets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use something like `docker run -it imagename bash` to enter into interactive shell.

Unfortunately, above will by default start a `non-login shell`, the `.bash_profile` only be called if it's in `login shell`, to make it works as `login shell`, you need to use next to enter into the container:

```
docker run -it imagename bash -l
```

> -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell

**Minimal Example**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
RUN echo "export ABC=1" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run --rm -it abc:1 bash
[root@669149c2bc8b /]# env | grep ABC
[root@669149c2bc8b /]#
[root@669149c2bc8b /]# exit
$ docker run --rm -it abc:1 bash -l
[root@7be9b9b8e906 /]# env | grep ABC
ABC=1
```

You can see with `-l` to make it as login shell, `.bash_profile` be executed.